# Recursively Traversing XML DOM Tree in Java

Tags: java, xml, recursion

I am new to Java Programming. I have written a recursive procedure as follows:

```
public static String treeWalk2(Element element, String tofind) {
    String result = "";
    for ( int i = 0, size = element.nodeCount(); i < size; i++ ) {
        Node node = element.node(i);
        if ( node instanceof Element ) {
            result = treeWalk2( (Element) node, tofind );
        }
        else {
            if (node.asXML().toLowerCase().equals(tofind)) {
                result = node.getUniquePath();
                System.out.println(node.getUniquePath());
                break;                    
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to find an element in DOM Tree matching some string ("tofind" parameter in the procedure). If the type of the current node is an instance of Element then it will call itself. But when the value of the node is equal to "tofind" string then it will return the unique path of that node. I tried it with an xml file but the return value of the procedure is always "". You can see in the code I also write the unique path, if found, to the screen and it is giving me the desired result. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: it will return empty string "" because it could not find anything since it already initialized with empty string.  I would suggest to return the string instead of using break statement in following if block node.asXML().toLowerCase().equals(tofind) .... return result this will break and return the result at same time.

Comment: if I do not initialise it then the there is an error saying "variable might not have been initialized".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use return instead of break; like below

```
 if (node.asXML().toLowerCase().equals(tofind)) {
                result = node.getUniquePath();
                System.out.println(node.getUniquePath());
                return node.getUniquePath();
```

}

Comment: @AgusSanjaya are using a library for it.  if System.out.println(node.getUniquePath()); is system.print.out print the correct result.